# Trusted Web Activity: Not able to remove URL header

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity, digital-assets-links

I am exploring the Trusted Web Activity concepts and trying to launch it like this -

```
final CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
final CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();    
customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(TrustedWebUtils.EXTRA_LAUNCH_AS_TRUSTED_WEB_ACTIVITY, true);
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, Uri.parse(wrappedTargetUrl));
```

I used google's asset link generator [here](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) and tested it for the domain. It shows successful linking. Also, I am using the correct app signing key from Playstore. Still, it is not hiding the URL bar for me. I have looked and tried all the available options on StackOverflow and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the Url bar of a Trusted Web Activity it requires an association between the Android application and the website. The association must be established in both ways, linking **from the Application to the Website** and **from the Website to the Application**.

**Establish an association from Application to the Website**

1.Add `asset_statements` String `app>res>values>strings.xml` like below and change the contents for the site attribute to match the schema and domain opened by the Trusted Web Activity:

```
<resources>
    <string name="asset_statements">
        [{
            \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],
            \"target\": {
                \"namespace\": \"web\",
                \"site\": \"https://my.site.com\"}
        }]
    </string>
</resources>
```

2.Add the above `asset_statements` into your AndroidManifest.xml as `meta-data` under `application` tag like below and set the correct `data scheme and host` in your Launcher Activity:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my.application">

    <application>

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

        <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>

           <!--
             This intent-filter allows the Trusted Web Activity to handle Intents to open the app
           -->
          <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <!-- To handle links to the target URL-->
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="my.site.com"/>
          </intent-filter>
       </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Establish an association from Website to the Application**

You have to upload an `assetlinks.json` file into your website under the path: `https://my.site.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` where assetlinks.json should look like this:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.my.application",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["5B:49:F7:CB:BL:C8:6K:CJ:5F:D8:33:2A:DA:FA:71:18:88:N9:49:9C:D3:66:98:35:B4:A2:2C:EC:B9:65:6C:65"]
  }
}]
```

From the above file you have to set the correct **Package Name** and the correct **SHA-256 Fingerprint** (Keystore signature Hash).

There is an easy way to generate the above `assetlinks.json file` and the above hash from Android Studio. You have to go to Android Studio `Tools > App Links Assistant` and click the `Open Digital Asset Links File Generator` and add your site domain, the application package name and select your release keystore file like below and click `Generate Digital Asset Links file` Button to generate the `assetlinks.json` which is ready to be uploaded to the site. There is also a very helpful link which describes the association [Associate your app with your website](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing#associatesite)

[image: digital_asset_link]

To verify that the link is correct there is a `Link and Verify` Button to verify that the association from Website to Application is correct like in the below image sample:

[image: link verification]

After the above steps if the Sha256 which was uploaded to the site was for Release keystore you have to generate a release apk file which now if opened you should see that the Header Url Bar was removed successfully. I have tested the above steps and it works as expected.

**Note:**
In case you have opted into having Google Play sign your releases with a key they generated, you simply need to copy the **App signing key certificate SHA-256 fingerprint** under the **Google Play Console -> Setup -> App Integrity** and put it in the assetlinks.json file.